# Ordering menu items when some are excluded in bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have a navbar which contains some menu items that collapse when in mobile mode and some that do not. I am having trouble getting the collapsing menu item (my log out link) to sit to the **right** of the non-collapsing menu items (glyphicon links) when in non-mobile mode.

How can I achieve the desired navbar-right layout below?

[Current navbar-right layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOPsT.png)

[Desired navbar-right layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pith.png)

My HTML:

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs-block clearfix"></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you just need the UL containing log out to sit to the right of the ul containing Home, About, and contact? (if possible, please add more code or maybe make a sample on codepen and post to here, that way I can fix the problem on code pen and send you the solution)

Comment: I want Home, About and Contact to be aligned to the left and the glyphicons and log out to be aligned to the right. The log out button should be furthest to the right.

Comment: [Bootply link](https://www.bootply.com/NBW8RrCTCG)

Comment: Do you want it to only be like that in desktop mode or also in phone?

Comment: Only in desktop

Comment: If the solution works and you like it, please mark it as the solution and potentially give it a thumbs up:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this works well too:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left visible-xs">
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs-block clearfix"></div>
    <div >
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left collapse navbar-collapse">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse">
        <li  class="pull-left"><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

To see it in action, copy and paste it into your Bootply example at 
https://www.bootply.com/NBW8RrCTCG